# How to delete 0 bytes files from a fat filesystem from within linux

Tags: linux, filesystems

I have an external hdd which is formatted with fat for use by both on linux and windows. The issue is that I can't delete some of the files I have which show up with size 0. Also, the modification timestamp (as detected by Krusader, the file manager I am using) is 1935. How can I delete these kind of files without affecting the running fs?

Comment: It would help to know why you can't delete them - without the error message it'll be hard to help you.

Comment: I agree with @CryHavok, otherwise use "rm -f"

Comment: Doh, sorry, here's the error: rm: cannot remove `file': Input/output error

Comment: Have you run `fsck` or equivalent on the file system?

Comment: “Input/output error” points to a damaged filesystem or a damaged disk. Do any messages show up in `/var/log/kern.log` (better check from the time you plug in the disk to the time you get the error)?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your FAT table is damaged.  You can run `fsck` to see if this is indeed the case.  But I would recommend finding other tools (ie. [Testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk)) to fix FAT table before you run `fsck` to "fix" it...if you value the other data on the drive.